# Question about wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress

I have started a wordpress blog hosted on (free)wordpress.com. Now it has good alexa ranking. I post after two or three days. I want to earn from this blog via google adsense. What is the best way to earn money from this. Please Give Suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, this is 1.) off-topic and 2.) unclear. If you already know about Adsense, what is your question exactly? Anyway, this is definitely off-topic here. In a more refined form (but **not as it is!**) it may have a chance on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buy a domain and hosting, Host wordpress blog there. Work hard to generate unique and quality contents.

Then apply for google adsence account...!
That's it.